# Parsing a file based on byte sections

Tags: go

I am parsing a file, the file is read byte by byte and I have instructions on which byte represents what part of the file.

Orders file:

1. first 4 bytes is the version
2. next 4 bytes is an integer, representing how many orders to expect.
3. for each order (from #2), 4 bytes integer is the order ID.

So to parse this, I first load the file:

```
file, err := os.Open("orders.abc")

version := make([]byte, 4)
c, err := file.Read(version)
fmt.Printf("read %d, version is %d", c, version)

orderCount := make([]byte, 4)
c2, err := file.Read(orderCount)
fmt.Printf("read %d, orderCount is %d", c2, orderCount)

for i := 0; i < orderCount_as_int; i++ {

  orderId := make([]byte, 4)
  c3, err := file.Read(orderId)     
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to be parsing a file like this?

Also, how can I convert the version/orderCount into an integer so I can use the value?

Comment: Use `ReadFull` to make sure you get a complete read. How are the integer values encoded? Little endian, big endian, ascii, etc?

Comment: @JimB I have no idea, the documentation does not specify so I have to guess for now.

Comment: So you need to look at the bytes and see what it looks like, or show an example of the data and what value you expect.

Comment: @jimB lets just assume it is Little endian...

Comment: The given answer shows one way, or see the other methods in `encoding/binary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [encoding/binary.Read](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read) rather than calling Read directly. e.g.

```
var version int32
err := binary.Read(file, binary.LittleEndian, &version)
```

(also you need to know whether your data is in the file as big-endian or little-endian and choose the appropriate ByteOrder). The binary package will do the decoding for you.

Comment: Thanks!  what about for 4 byte characters, is there a specific method for that or I just cast it using the `strings(...)` function?

Comment: @Blankman, strings in go are utf8. By “4 byte character”, do you mean [`utf32`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode/utf32)?

Comment: @JimB Yes I believe so...